# android: content provider : Service crashes on staring - Unable to get provider sensordata.collector.SurveyDbProvider

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I have built my own content provider. Many applications have to share this database.

But when I start my service it crashes. I didn't even get any exceptions in the log.

Looks like issue with manifest, since after I added tags realted to provider issue started.

```
Package:sensordata.collector
Clas name : SurveyDbProvider [SurveyDbProvider extends ContentProvider]
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="sensordata.collector"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <permission
        android:name="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.READ"
        android:label="@string/perm_label"        
        android:description="@string/perm_label" />

     <permission
        android:name="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.WRITE"
        android:label="@string/perm_label"        
        android:description="@string/perm_label" />

    <uses-permission android:name="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.WRITE" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.READ" /> 


In application tag :

  <provider android:name="sensordata.collector.SurveyDbProvider"
         android:authorities="sensordata.collector" 
         android:readPermission="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.READ"
         android:writePermission="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.WRITE" />  

    </application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

</manifest>
```

Please help.

Comment: some how not able to paste the entitre manifest 
    <provider android:name="sensordata.collector.SurveyDbProvider"
         android:authorities="sensordata.collector" 
         android:readPermission="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.READ"
         android:writePermission="sensordata.collector.SURVEY_DATA.permission.WRITE" />  
    
    </application>

Comment: Can anyone please tell the changes to be done in manifest. I have created a content provider SurveyDbProvider  and want to access in this application as well as others. Also I am getting run time exception : RuntimeException: Unable to get provider sensordata.collector.SurveyDbProvider

Answer (score 0):

The authority is missing the ContentProvider name. It should be:

```
<provider android:name="sensordata.collector.SurveyDbProvider"
          android:authorities="sensordata.collector.surveydbprovider" ... />
```

And as a good practice you should declare a CONTENT_URI constant matching this authority inside the provider class.

Answer (score 0):

Does your provider has a public constructor ? 
The sensordata.collector.SurveyDbProvider has to be initializable, so it cannot be for example abstract class.

if you do not see exceptions and you are using Eclipse, press F8, maybe multiple times and check your LogCat